# Mapbox property functions: base value

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Checking MapBox Street-v9 style I found strange notation, and I could not verify by saerching SO, docs and manuals exact meaning of it.

```
    "paint": {
        "background-color": {
            "base": 1,
            "stops": [ [11, "hsl(35, 32%, 91%)"], [13, "hsl(35, 12%, 89%)"]]
        }
    }
```

Suspicious here for me is "base": 1. 
I understand, in case of line-width or similar, base 1 means default width of 1.

But here property is not integer, so what does it mean exactly?
First stop? Starting from 0 or 1?

P.S.
there are more examples of similar usage:

```
        "line-cap": {
            "base": 1,
            "stops": [ [0, "butt"], [11 "round"] ]
        },
```

Comment: note that this syntax is deprecated and has been replaced by expressions, specifically the "interpolate" expression https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-interpolate

Comment: this im aware of. needed some clarifications to be able to read legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **base**
>
> *Optional number. Default is 1.*
>
> The exponential base of the interpolation curve. It controls the rate
>   at which the function output increases. Higher values make the output
>   increase more towards the high end of the range. With values close to
>   1 the output increases linearly.
>
> https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#function-base

Comment: Somehow i missed this paragraph.